# CRS01(TE85L,Q,M) Schottky diode is open both ways

Tags: diodes, schottky, leakage-current

I was testing my PCB when I noticed that I get +12 V on USB Vbus line, even though I placed a Schottky diode to block it.

[image]

The idea is to use +12 V voltage source to provide power and to connect USB to PC to get data log, but also to have a possibility to use +5V of Vbus, when +12 V is not present.

My Schottky diode has 30 V reverse voltage rating, but when I connect +12 V, I get same voltage on my USB port, so the diode must be open, I tried changing it for a new, but same problem occurs, I even assembled new PCB with just Schottky diode, to check if it was a problem and yes, diode doesn't block reverse voltage.

Can someone explain why this happens? Why diode act as a regular wire? Here is a link to datasheet: https://www.mouser.lt/datasheet/2/408/CRS01_datasheet_en_20131101-1134894.pdf

Comment: Do you mean the diode _conducts_  both ways? Open means doesn't conduct, like an open switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schottky diodes can have poor reverse leakage current.

This is the graph from your data sheet link: -

[image]

As you should be able to see, with a 10 volt reverse bias (nearly equivalent to your 12 volt supply), you might be getting up to 100 μA flowing and, if you are measuring that voltage without load, then you will see a high voltage. Try adding a 1 kΩ resistor as load and hopefully you'll see the 12 volts drop to something small like 100 mV.

For your actual circuit, I'd be tempted to add a 5.6 volt Zener across the 5 volt USB line to ensure that it can never reach 12 volts (due to diode reverse leakage current).

Answer (score 2):

That is normal.

If you simply measure voltage over a diode that is in an open circuit, there will be 0V over it. Just like how a resistor has 0V over it when there is no current through it.

So if one end of diode (or resistor) is at 12V, the other end will be at 12V too.

So in order to see less that 12V on the anode, there would need to be some load on the 5V node that closes a circuit to ground.

Bur Schottky diodes have a lot of leakage current compared to a regular diode. You may not want to use a Schottky diode, as it may leak too much current from 12V to 5V node.

And just FYI, the USB Type-C interface is designed wrong. No compliant Type-C device will give any power to your device, and won't communicate with your device, as they can't detect anything being connected. It will only work with a Type-A to Type-C cable as they are allowed to always forcibly provide 5V.

Comment: yes, that is the Idea to use Type-A to Type-C cable to connect it to PC and to program the mcu.

Comment: It's still wrong even if you plan to use a cable that works. Next person might use Type-C to Type-C cable and it won't work.